# Translating code comments written in another spoken language

Tags: translate, comments, spoken-language

I've just inherited some C code from a German programmer, and all of the comments are, naturally, in German.  As I've forgotten most of my high school German, this is a slight problem.

Does anyone know of any translation tools that are code-aware; meaning it will only translate language within comments?  The project has many files, being able to operate on all of them at once would also be fantastic.

I'm currently copying-and-pasting into Google Translate, and while this is less than ideal, it can at least get me some answers.

Comment: arg, got a similar problem.. You find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I had briefly considered writing a tool to do it, as suggested by Pekka and Sean below, but I ended up just slogging through it with Google Translate.  In fact, the biggest issue ended up not being the comments, it was variable names!  We're all taught that single-letter variable names are horrible choices, but when the variable names are in another language, they may as well be "foo", "bar", or "x"!

Comment: Hah, brutal....

Comment: Always wondered how people who don't speak english code

Comment: The same way people who DO speak English write code, I suppose.  In our case, the software was written by a German, in Germany, for other Germans.  Plus, the author's English was far better than MY German, so I cut him some slack.  I can't fault the author for the comments and variable names, however the bugs are another story!

Comment: No, I mean the key words of a programing language are all in english.  If you are doing a for loop in english "for" makes sense while in german that would be a "zum" loop (according to google translate).

Answer (score 0):

I would only know exactly how to do this in java, but I am sure there is a way to do this in C as well, as the tools exist:

1. Grab a parser that understands C source files ([this one](http://www-prima.inrialpes.fr/Ravi/cparse.html) sounds ok, but I don't know much about C)
2. build a syntax tree. iterate over all nodes of the tree, replacing the text of all comment nodes with translated text.
3. write the tree back to a new source file (perhaps in a different directory).

Answer (score 0):

Very broadly, this should be possible to do using Google translation's [Ajax API](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/ajaxlanguage/) and a regex function that can deal with callbacks - I don't think JS's built-in regex functions are up to the task but I'm sure there are libraries out there. You would have to build a regular expression that can isolate the comments, send each chunk to the API, and return the translated result in the callback function.